# xarray - plotting two Datasets into one figure

Tags: python-xarray

I have two xarray Datasets. I simply used the xarray plot functionality and cartopy to plot the datasets.

```
Dataset 1 (main dataset):
```

[image]

```
Dataset 2 (masking dataset):
```

[image]

Both datasets contain the same Lon and Lat dimensions and coordinates. What I want to achieve is to use the areas (value = 0) in Dataset 2 to mask out the same areas in Dataset 1. The color map in Dataset 1 remains "coolwarm" (blue to red) while the areas masked out should be drawn in green.

Any examples of xarray plotting two Datasets onto one Axe and Figure would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xarray.where](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.where.html) for masking, described in more detail [here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html#masking-with-where). Here is an example where 2 datasets are created and one is masked via the other.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dummy data
temperature = 15 + 8 * np.random.randn(2, 2)
land = [[1,0], [0,0]]

lon = [[-99.83, -99.32], [-99.79, -99.23]]
lat = [[42.25, 42.21], [42.63, 42.59]]

# create first dataset with data
DS1 = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        temperature=(["x", "y"], temperature),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        lon=(["x", "y"], lon),
        lat=(["x", "y"], lat)
    ),
)

# create second dataset with mask
DS2 = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars=dict(
        land=(["x", "y"], land),
    ),
    coords=dict(
        lon=(["x", "y"], lon),
        lat=(["x", "y"], lat)
    ),
)

# masking
DA_masked = DS1.temperature.where(DS2.land==0)

# plotting
plt.pcolormesh(DA_masked.lon, DA_masked.lat, DA_masked)
plt.show()
```

Keep in mind that both datasets, or more specifically both dataarrays, have to have the same dimensions, otherwise the masking will not work.